# Generate custom jwt-token and Authenticate user, Spring Security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, jwt

**Situation:** I have a token from another API that contains user info and user is already logged. I want to authenticate this user info (already extracted) and generate a token with my spring security application.

**Notes:** I'm using Jwt custom enchancer and sorry for newbie way of posting.

My security conf:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
    tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain).reuseRefreshTokens(false)
            .exceptionTranslator(loggingExceptionTranslator()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
}

@Bean
public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey(properties.getAuth().getSigningKey());
    return accessTokenConverter;
}

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
}

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new PlaceTokenEnhancer();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved my own problem debugging and searching!

```
//load full user info (custom method)
UserDetails userDetails = placeUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(responseUser.getEmail());

            Set<String> scope = new HashSet<>();
            scope.add("read"); scope.add("write");
            OAuth2Request auth2Request = new OAuth2Request(null, "smthg", userDetails.getAuthorities(), true,
                    scope, null, null, null, null);
    //Custom OAuth2Token
            PlaceAuthenticationToken placeAuthenticationToken = new PlaceAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            placeAuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated(true);
            placeAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));

            OAuth2Authentication auth = new OAuth2Authentication(auth2Request, placeAuthenticationToken);
            auth.setAuthenticated(true);
            auth.setDetails(placeAuthenticationToken.getDetails());
            accessToken =  authServer.createAccessToken(auth);

            DefaultOAuth2AccessToken tkn = (DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken;
            tkn.setRefreshToken(null);
            accessToken = tkn;
```

Basically All you have to do is generate Authentication using Oauth2Request and use .createAccessToken()!

Maybe it could help someone else!